# Querydsl vs ES Querydsl

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have been asked to look into Querydsl. So, I've been searching on line and there appears to be two of them: one sponsored by Mysema and the other created by Elastic Search. I'm a bit confused about the differences in the functionality. Is Elastic Search's Querydsl an expansion on Querydsl? Can anyone point me to or provide an example that compares the uses of the two?

So far this is what I know:

*Querydsl*

- Java Framework
- Supports JPA, JDO, SQL, Java collections, RDF, Lucene, Hibernate Search, and MongoDB
- Generates type-safe queries with a syntax is similar to SQL

*ES Querydsl*

- Based on JSON
- Similar to REST Query DSL
- Query language for full-text and structured search

Comment: To add even more confusion to this, someone in Solr decided it would be a great idea to name their query language based in JSON as [JSON Query DSL](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/json-query-dsl.html) Originality is scarce these days...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using QueryDsl (Java framework) for a while. As far as I know, they are two different things.

The [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/) is a framework to write type-safe queries in Java.

While the [ES Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html) is a language based on JSON to write queries in ES.

Comment: Let me answer my question here... it stands for Query Domain Specific Language. Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html

<br />
Cheers :D

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are going with version 2.x it's recommended that you just use a plain http client and use the ES query dsl, as ES usually yanks out classes between versions.

Comment: So you are saying not to use ES query dsl at all? I'm still confused on how it is different from query dsl.

Comment: All I'm saying that it'd be easier to build applications using the Query DSL from a maintainability stand point by externalizing your queries rather than sticking them into your code and dealing with broken code as part of  each ES upgrade.

Comment: So going back to my question, are Mysema's Query DSL and ES Query DSL are the same thing?